# Unable to run Javascript validations with Flask

Tags: javascript, flask

I am making a simple Flask registration app, at the time of registration there are standard validations that I want to add like email can't be blank and others, but instead of adding validations at the server end (just for testing) I am trying to add validations with *Vanilla JS* but somehow I can only force one.

Not want to use WTForms.

If I use the e.preventDefault() method then even after all the validations are met the form still does not submits as it stops the default submit action of the form and if I remove the method then the JS validations are overrun and the success page is shown.

**How do I ensure that JS validations work and form only gets submitted after client side validations are met?**

Code:

```
@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])
def success():
 return render_template('success.html')
```

JS:

```
rgBtn.onclick = function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
if(rgEmail.value === "") {
    alert("email cannot be empty")
    rgEmailLabel.style.color = "orangered"
}
else {
    rgEmailLabel.style.color = "#212121"
    console.log(rgEmail.value)
    console.log(rgPass.value)
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `e.preventDefault()` only if the validations fail

```
rgBtn.onclick = function(e) {
  if(rgEmail.value === "") {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert("email cannot be empty")
    rgEmailLabel.style.color = "orangered"
  }
  else {
    rgEmailLabel.style.color = "#212121"
    console.log(rgEmail.value)
    console.log(rgPass.value)
  }
}
```